# Module not found error: package path ./cjs/react.development is not exported from package

Tags: javascript, html, css, node.js, reactjs

*I'm getting the following error while trying to compile a code in Reactjs. I'm new to Reactjs.*

```
Module not found: Error: Package path ./cjs/react.development is not exported from package /Users/mansi/letsgrowmore/to-do-list/my-react-app/node_modules/react (see exports field in /Users/mansi/letsgrowmore/to-do-list/my-react-app/node_modules/react/package.json)
ERROR in ./src/Components/Todolist.js 7:0-51
Module not found: Error: Package path ./cjs/react.development is not exported from package /Users/mansi/letsgrowmore/to-do-list/my-react-app/node_modules/react (see exports field in /Users/mansi/letsgrowmore/to-do-list/my-react-app/node_modules/react/package.json)


webpack compiled with 1 error
```

```
import React from 'react';
import useState from 'react/cjs/react.development';
import Todoform from './Todoform';

export default function TodoList() {
  const [todos, setTodos] = useState([]);
  const addTask = task => {
    if (!task.text) {
      return;
    }
    const newTodos = [task, ...todos];
    setTodos(newTodos);
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <Todoform addTask={addTask}></Todoform>
    </div>
  );
}
```

I tried npm update, downgrading the version but still same error.

Comment: Please try to use `import React, { useEffect, useRef, useState } from 'react';`

Comment: @LikiCrus did that and it worked!Thank you. However, it gives warning.

src/Components/Todolist.js
  Line 1:16:  'useEffect' is defined but never used  no-unused-vars
  Line 1:27:  'useRef' is defined but never used     no-unused-vars

Search for the keywords to learn more about each warning.
To ignore, add // eslint-disable-next-line to the line before.

WARNING in src/Components/Todolist.js
  Line 1:16:  'useEffect' is defined but never used  no-unused-vars
  Line 1:27:  'useRef' is defined but never used     no-unused-vars

webpack compiled with 1 warning

Comment: remove `useEffect`, `useRef` in import statement.

Answer (score 0):

The issue in your code is that you are using functions that are never imported from React.

---

To resolve this issue, you need to import the functions that you are using from React.

To do this, we will use an importing technique called **tree-shaking**. This is basically the use of getting specific functions/variables from an import, instead of getting everything and only using a few things. This technique can greatly increase speed and reduce bundle size.

In your React file, replace this line of code:

```js
import React from "react";
```

With this:

```js
import React, { useState } from "react";
```

This will import the `useState` function from the React library.

If you use another function from React (e.g. `useEffect`), then you need to import it the same way as `useState` was imported.

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
```

Basically, every time you need to import a function/variable from React, separate it with a comma (`,`) in the curly braces (`{}`).

---

In conclusion, to resolve the issue, you need to import the functions/variables that you are using.